# Magento getAction() not work on 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, action

Hello is there any alternative condition for below condition. I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2.

```
$action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();

if ($action->getFullActionName() == 'sales_order_reorder')  {
// Some code here
}
```

I got null `$action`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

again same kind of answer from my side for you,

You can try below code for your requirement

```
if (in_array('sales_order_reorder', Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles())){
     //your code
}
```

Comment: can you please say why my conditon not work?

Comment: @KetanKpBorada I dont have idea about your condition need to check what data we get in `getFrontController` method and its need debugging

Answer (score 1):

Use below code will work in observer to get full action name

```
        /*
         * Get full Action controller name in Observer
         */
        $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
        $module = $request->getControllerModule();
        $module_controller = $request->getControllerName();
        $module_controller_action = $request->getActionName();

        $fullActionName = $module."_".$module_controller."_".$module_controller_action;

        echo $fullActionName;
```